# Python GET Rest API - package is downloaded but I cannot open it (invalid)

Tags: python, rest, python-3.8

I must run python to get some artifacts from repository in following syntax (invoked from batch with its variables) so this part to pass arguments is not changeable.

```
python get_artifacts.py %USERNAME%:%PASSWORD% http://url/artifactory/package.zip
```

My python script is the following:

```
import sys
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

def get_artifact(url, save_artifact_name, username, password, chunk_size=128):
    try:
        get_method = requests.get(url, 
                        auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), stream=True)

        with open(save_artifact_name, 'wb') as artifact:
            for chunk in get_method.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
                artifact.write(chunk)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
        sys.exit(str(error))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    username_and_password = sys.argv[1].split(':')
    username = username_and_password[0]
    password = username_and_password[1]

    url = sys.argv[2]
    save_artifact_name = url.split("/")[-1]

    print(f'Retrieving artifact {save_artifact_name}...')
    get_artifact(url, save_artifact_name, username, password)
    print("Finished successfully!")
```

Now I CAN see my package downloaded, but my zip package is **invalid**.
Of course with some other tool like **curl.exe** the same works.
So definitely I am missing something in python script but not able to determine what am I missing (download works but package is invalid).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Has the downloaded file the expected size? Does the file start with "PK"?

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks for the involvment. It does not have expected size - downloaded 5KB instead of 110MB. I will add this to the question. what do you mean with "PK"?

Comment: Usually zip-files begin with ASCII letters "PK" to identify them as having zip data format.

Comment: I guess that the file actually contains an error message in HTML which may give more clues what went wrong.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I do not have HTML response in my script. Can you please tell me what else can be the issue? I tried with `get_method.content()` but it doesn't work..

Comment: Did you try to load the zip-file in a hex viewer or at least a text editor to see what it contains?

Comment: A quick way (assuming you have a 'hexdump' called 'hd') of checking the header would be to try: "hd package.zip | head" then the first line of this should look something like: "00000000  50 4b 03 04 14 00 08 00  08 00 75 93 a5 50 00 00  |PK........u..P..|" so that 'PK' is the one that Michael is mentioning above that all .zip files will begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer that is MUCH closer to the original, including the chunking that will work with minimal memory.  It simply places the open() before the downloading code:

```
import sys
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

def get_artifact(url, save_artifact_name, username, password, chunk_size=128):
    try:

        with open(save_artifact_name, 'wb') as artifact:

            get_method = requests.get(url,
                        auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), stream=True)
            for chunk in get_method.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
                artifact.write(chunk)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
        sys.exit(str(error))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    username_and_password = sys.argv[1].split(':')
    username = username_and_password[0]
    password = username_and_password[1]

    url = sys.argv[2]
    save_artifact_name = url.split("/")[-1]

    print(f'Retrieving artifact {save_artifact_name}...')
    get_artifact(url, save_artifact_name, username, password)
    print("Finished successfully!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're streaming the file a few bytes at a time and writing each chunk to the file but writing the file a-new each time so I suspect you're just seeing the last chunk in the file.  Unless the file is hugely huge, you should be able to simply load the entire thing into memory then write it out.  Here's the modified version:

```
import sys
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

def get_artifact(url, save_artifact_name, username, password):
    try:
        get_method = requests.get(url,
            auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))

        with open(save_artifact_name, 'wb') as artifact:
            artifact.write(get_method.content)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
        sys.exit(str(error))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    username_and_password = sys.argv[1].split(':')
    username = username_and_password[0]
    password = username_and_password[1]

    url = sys.argv[2]
    save_artifact_name = url.split("/")[-1]

    print(f'Retrieving artifact {save_artifact_name}...')
    get_artifact(url, save_artifact_name, username, password)
    print("Finished successfully!")
```

That should fetch the entire file in one go and write it to your output.  I've just tested this with a 5MB test file I found online and it downloaded just lovely.

The chunk size is no longer needed as you're not downloading in chunks. :)

Comment: unfortunately got error: `TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "retrieve_artifacts.py", line 26, in <module>
    get_artifact(url, save_artifact_name, username, password)
  File "retrieve_artifacts.py", line 11, in get_artifact
    artifact.write(get_method.content())
TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable`

Comment: If  I set `artifact.write(get_method.content)` instead of the `content()` then again I am getting 5KB file instead of 110MB :(

Comment: can you please suggest what else might be the solution for this issue?

Comment: @AndreyS Sorry, I did put () on the the get_method.content when they shouldn't have been there but removing them led to the working code.  I've included the entrire code in the answer now having just tested it and it worked as expected so I hope it also does for you!

Comment: I accepted the answer thanks. Can you please provide me simple clarification when I should use chunks and when the "all-in-one" solution? also what is better from performance perspective (in terms for downloading e.g packages of 500MB)? Thank you

Comment: You'd use chunks if either you want to process the file 'as it downloads' or you don't have the memory to store it.  In the latter case, an answer closer to your original approach would be to open the file before you start the download then write each chunk as it appears, closing the file afterwards.  I'd consider using chunks larger than 128 though as that's probably going to slow things down.  It's usually acceptable to use 32K or even much larger unless you're operating in an environment such as an embedded controller with little memory.

Comment: I've added a second answer that is actually almost identical to your posted original!  It would have probably been a more appropriate answer in retrospect...

Comment: thanks - and from the speed perspective what is better approach? regarding the memory that should not be such a big concern in our case...

Comment: I'd experiment.  Do a couple runs with different chunk_size, starting with 128 then double each time.  If you can afford the memory you should be able to go quite large.